# How to read/write CLOB, XMLTYPE with JDBC Connector in mule?

Tags: oracle, mule

we are trying to read CLOB value from a jdbc query in mule, when we run in debug mode we are able to see the value of the jdbc query as SIZE=3  (3 rows in db) but when we are using object to json transformer it is giving the below error.

```
"org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: Closed Connection (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedList[0]->org.mule.util.CaseInsensitiveHashMap["INPUT"]->oracle.sql.CLOB["dbaccess"]) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException). Message payload is of type: LinkedList (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: LinkedList"
```

We also tried to select XMLTYPE value from a db using select query but getting the below error eventhough the table has records in it.

```
org.mule.api.messagingexception: null (java.lang.nullpointerexception). message payload is of type: string
```

Comment: Can you post your flow here, so we could see whats wrong?

Comment: '<sub-flow name="SPCall">
        <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="IIW_Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>'

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify this guy's solution a little bit, but it works.

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/40791/unable-to-convert-clob-to-json.html

here is my version I used in MuleSoft

```
clobPricing=(java.sql.Clob)payload[0].PRICING
bodyText=clobPricing?.getCharacterStream()
targetString=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(bodyText)
payload=targetString 
return payload
```

I also added a set payload right after the groovy transform and a dataweave after that to supplement the json output with additional mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing CLOBs can be done very easily with zero java code. The example below has been tested with Mule 3.8.5.

The database table is quite simple for the sandbox project.

```
CREATE TABLE T_ORDER ( 
    ID SERIAL NOT NULL,
    JSON CLOB,      
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

**SELECT SQL with CLOB**

Reading the database table with given orderNo.

```
<db:select config-ref="databaseConfiguration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query>
            <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM T_ORDER WHERE ID = :orderNo]]>
    </db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="orderNo" value="#[flowVars.orderNo]" />
</db:select>
```

To convert the CLOB to a Mule readable object, we use the static Apache Utils function in the flow component.

```
<set-payload value="#[payload[0].JSON.getCharacterStream()]" />
<set-payload value="#[org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(payload)]" />
```

My sandbox project stores the full json object to the CLOB database field (should be done only sandbox projects).

```
{
  "order_no": 1,
  "order_date": "2019-07-01",
  "order_status": "NEW",
  "customer_no": 79000001,
  "order_items": [
    {
      "material_no": 100068,
      "material_text": "Black T-Shirt Roundneck",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 24.99,
      "currency": "EUR"
    }
  ]
}
```

**INSERT SQL with CLOB**

Insert CLOB into table is very simple by using the following configuration. I also configured the auto generated key options to the primary back after the sql insert has been completed.

```
<db:insert config-ref="databaseConfiguration" autoGeneratedKeys="true" autoGeneratedKeysColumnNames="ID" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query>
            <![CDATA[INSERT INTO T_ORDER (JSON) VALUES (:json)]]>
    </db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="json" type="CLOB" value="#[payload]" />
</db:insert>
```

Hope that helps.